# How to convert a date character vector to Date format while keeping only year and month information?

Tags: r

I have a character vector containing dates in the format "YYYY-MM", such as:

`date_vec <- c("2020-01", "2020-02", "2020-03", "2020-04")`

I want to convert this vector to a Date format in R, but I want to keep only the year and month information without adding any information about the day of the month. Specifically, I want the resulting Date objects to have the format `"%Y-%m"` and not `"%Y-%m-%d"`.

I have tried using the `as.Date()` function in R with the format argument set to `"%Y-%m"`, but this seems returns `NA`.

```
as.Date(date_vec, format = "%Y-%m")
#return NA NA NA NA
```

Any thoughts, please?

Comment: It's not possible to create a `Date` object/vector without "day", hence your NAs. Packages like `yearmon` create a numeric vector inside a custom index class so it's not a `Date` object, just a representation. `lubridate` will convert your strings to `Date`, but it will add a day if it's missing. It would be useful to know why you need these in `Date` format. Are you wanting to conduct time series analysis or similar? It's just that unless you absolutely need a `Date` object for a particular process, there are numerous options for conducting analysis that can call the d/m/y parts in a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to work with just months, you can use zoo's `yearmon` class.

**EDIT:** Simplified answer thanks to G. Grothendieck's suggestion.

```r
date_vec <- c("2020-01", "2020-02", "2020-03", "2020-04")

zoo::as.yearmon(date_vec)

[1] "Jan 2020" "Feb 2020" "Mar 2020" "Apr 2020"
```

Comment: Probably best to use `library(zoo)` and omit the `zoo::` before `as.yearmon` in case there are further calculations with the yearmon object to be sure it can find further yearmon methods.  For example, if in a fresh instance of R we write `x <- zoo::as.yearmon("2000-01"); as.Date(x)` then we would get an error since it would not be able to find the `as.Date.yearmon` method.  If we write `library(zoo); x <- as.yearmon("2000-01"); as.Date(x)` there would be no problem.